# How to fully rename tmux window

Tags: tmux

I have such tmux config related to the window naming

```
set -g window-status-format '#[fg=colour235,bg=colour252,bold] #I #(pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo ${pwd####*/}) #W '

set -g window-status-current-format '#[fg=colour234,bg=colour39]⮀#[fg=black,bg=colour39,noreverse,bold] #{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=colour228],} #I #(pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo ${pwd####*/}) #W #[fg=colour39,bg=colour234,nobold]⮀'
```

Here's a screenshot of this:
[image]

The auto naming window works great for me until I want to change it.

I want to have an ability to fully rename the window name, currently I can do only this:
[image]

I don't need the folder name in my desired window name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
set -g window-status-format '#[fg=colour235,bg=colour252,bold] #I #W '
set -g window-status-current-format '#[fg=colour234,bg=colour39]⮀#[fg=black,bg=colour39,noreverse,bold] #{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=colour228],} #I #W #[fg=colour39,bg=colour234,nobold]⮀'
```

I deleted the part related to folder name

```
#(pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo ${pwd####*/})
```